# jgraph port size

Tags: java, swing

I am using jgraph v 5.9.2.0 with JDK7.

I want to increase the size of the input port. I create a port using:

```
org.jgraph.graph.DefaultPort newPort = new org.jgraph.graph.DefaultPort();
```

Can someone please tell how to increase the size of this default port? I see there is one method: `org.jgraph.graph.PortView#setPortSize(int size)`. However, how can I get the reference of PortView?

Comment: Try JGraph [forum](http://forum.jgraph.com/) and [support](http://jgraph.com/support.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the static port size variable directly:

```
PortView.SIZE = 10;
```